# html form field validation

Tags: php, html

I have html form and I want to add validation on user input - example user name filed must start with alpha and zip code must  be numeric.

```
 > <tr>
<td>username</td>
<td><input type="text" name="user name" placeholder="Must start with Alpha"></td>
 </tr>

 > <tr>
<td>zipcode</td>
<td><input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Must be 5 digit numeric"></td>
 </tr>
```

is there any simple way to enforce this rule if not send error. I am new and this is for simple internal site prefer not complicated solution.

Comment: Look into regular expressions

Comment: Use regex and JavaScript to perform validation example: http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/form-validation-using-jquery-and-regular-expressions/

Comment: Unrelated: You probably shouldn't use a table here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're wanting a form verification and not an on the fly verification, I would suggest the html5 numeric fields in addition to a "pattern" attribute.

Comment: +1 for this. OP has already used HTML5 placeholder so I don't see a problem in html5 validations.

Comment: @AyeshKarunaratne: HTML5 placeholders are much more supported than html5 custom types.

Comment: @Truth Thanks for the clarification! Even IE9 sucks.

Comment: @Ayesh I have used HTML5 required pattern and work just fine. thanks!

Comment: Cheers!
Marking this reply the answer will help future users i think.

Answer (score 0):

This question is extremely googleable.  Here is a sample tutorial Google listed:

http://absolutewebdev.com/tutorials.php?result=8&topic=Validating_a_form_using_JavaScript_Regular_Expressions

Find others by googling something like 
form validation javascript regex

Comment: I didn't downvote this fyi. 
True that this has been discussed/demonstrated before. Even the right sidebar shows similar threads.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still trying to get a handle on what acceptable answers are here, I guess.